# Material-UI <Autocomplete /> different label than option value

Tags: autocomplete, material-ui

I have a [Material-UI `<Autocomplete />`](https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/) component I am using where you can type in someone's name and it will provide a list of people to select from. This is a pretty standard use case, however I need the selected item in the form to be different than the label.

Currently if you pick the entry labelled "John Smith", the text field will be filled with "John Smith". Instead, I want to fill the text field with that user's ID.

The data for autocomplete is an array of objects like this:

```
{ "name": "John Smith", "id": 123456789 }
```

How can I make the autocomplete component put the user ID in the text field instead of the user label?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can customize [renderOption](https://material-ui.com/api/autocomplete/) props in Material-UI `Autocomplete`

> Render the option, use getOptionLabel by default.
> **Signature**: `function(option: T, state: object) => ReactNode`
> **option**: The option to render.
> **state**: The state of the component.

As for the code

```
getOptionLabel={option => option.name}
renderOption={(option) => <span>{option.name}</span>}
```

Refer to the [demo](https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/#country-select) in an official document

Answer (score 5):

If you just want to display name in Textfield, You could try this

```
    getOptionLabel={option => option.id}
    renderOption={option => <>{option.name}</>}
```

If you want to display name in TextField and OptionLabel but want to get id as value of TextField in order to store id after form submission.
You could try this

```
    getOptionLabel={(option) => option.name}
    renderOption={(option) => (
      <>
        {option.name} ({option.surname})
      </>
    )}
    onChange={(event, newValue) => {
      setValue(newValue);
      setCustomValue(newValue.id);
    }}
```

using onChange event you could select any field of the option you want to get as value.In this example I stored id of the option in the state.
Complete working example is here https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-wlzr8?file=/demo.js:804-1084